# LaTeX Mode and Listings with $-signs?

Tags: latex, auctex, syntax-highlighting

I am using `LaTeX-Mode` and need to include some listings which contain dollar-signs:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Meteor Server: Bereitstellen einer entfernten Prozedur,label=lst:meteor-server-publish-rpc]
Meteor.Methods({
  addStar: function(messageId) {
    Messages.update(messageId, {
      $inc : { "stars" : 1 }
    });
  }
});
\end{lstlisting}
```

Sadly, this breaks syntax highlighting as emacs treats the contents of the `listing` block as "normal" LaTeX code.

[image: emacs with incorrect syntax highlighting]

Is there any way to tell emacs not to ignore certain blocks? I know I could use an external file and use that, but I would prefer to keep my source together.

This is running `GNU Emacs 24.5.1` and `AUCTeX 11.89`.

Comment: Do you have file parsing enabled?  If so, syntax highlighting would be correct.  If not, add the lines suggested at the beginning of the [AUCTeX manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html):
`(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)` (and read at least the "Quick Start" section of the manual, while you're at it)

Comment: That was a good read, but for some reason the problem persists even after customizing that variables.

Comment: What's the value of the `TeX-active-styles` variable (`C-h v TeX-active-styles`) in your `.tex` file buffer? The line suggested by JeanPierre is already in the style file associated to listings package, you shouldn't need to add it manually. Which version of AUCTeX and Emacs are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the possibly stupid question but hem, that was my problem. Do you actually `\usepackage{listings}` with the correct spelling?

Comment: @giordano I think I sorted it out (it does work like it should now for me) and updated my answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot guys! What a pleasant diskussion to wake up to, I will check this as soon as I arrive at work.

Comment: After checking this at work, it immediatly worked. For the moment I have proposed an edit to JeanPierre's very complete answer to incorporate @giordano's comment. Is that the correct process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntax highlighting would be correct if file parsing is enabled. First check whether the options suggested at the beginning of the [AUCTeX manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html) are enabled:

```
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

In general AUCTeX should not highlight verbatim-like environments.  How does it know these envs?  Section [3.1.4](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Verbatim-content.html#Verbatim-content) of AUCTex documentation says:

> 3.1.4 Verbatim macros and environments
>       Usually it is not desirable to have content to be typeset verbatim
>       highlighted according to LaTeX syntax.  Therefore this content will be
>       fontified uniformly with the face `font-latex-verbatim-face'.
>
> font-latex differentiates three different types of verbatim
>       constructs for fontification.  Macros with special characters like | as
>       delimiters, macros with braces, and environments.  Which macros and
>       environments are recognized is controlled by the variables
>       `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims`,
>       `LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces`, and `LaTeX-verbatim-environments`
>       respectively.

So you can tell AUCTeX about a new verb-like env by adding to your
init file something like:

```
(eval-after-load 'latex '(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments "myverb"))
```

However, verb-like envs of common latex packages (including
`lstlistings` from the `listings` package) can be automatically
detected and 'styles' applied.  By [parsing](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html#Parsing-Files) your file, AUCTeX sees the
`\usepackage{listings}` and so adds `lstlistings` to its list of
verb-like envs.

AUCTeX parses the file only if `TeX-parse-self` is set.  If
`TeX-auto-save` is set, it saves the found information in the `auto`
local directory.  Once the file exists, it gets the information from
it and does not re-parse the file.

To make it parse again (eg because your file changed), run `C-c C-n`
(`TeX-normal-mode`) (I found that I sometimes need to run it twice).
Actually, you can dispend setting any variable and just type `C-c C-n`
when you want your file to be parsed and styles applied.

Comment: This is correct in general, for a new verbatim-like environment, but in this concrete case AUCTeX already adds `lstlisting` to the list of verbatim environments, so maybe there are some problems in the configuration of Marcus Riemer.

Comment: @giordano It seems I have the same problem, `lstisting` is not added to the list (debian package auctex 11.87.3+deb8u1)., even with your suggestion applied. Adding `(eval-after-load 'latex '(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments "lstlisting"))` to my init file does work.

Comment: Please, answer [these questions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18975/latex-mode-and-listings-with-signs/18976?noredirect=1#comment28516_18975).