# Custom verbatim environments/macros in AucTeX

Tags: latex, auctex, syntax-highlighting

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{tscode}{}{}
\def\tscode|#1|{}

\begin{document}
\tsinline|efwe|
\begin{tscode}
efihw$feiw$
\end{tscode}
\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local: ("tscode")
% LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local: ("tsinline")
% End:
```

I've verified the buffer is loading as `LaTeX-mode` and that the variables listed have the quoted values given as the file-local value, but fontlock is still incorrect after saving&reverting the buffer:

[image: -]

I've had this working before, but I'm not sure what changed in my configuration.  I'm assuming no incompatible changes with AucTeX have been introduced in the last three months or so.

Related:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111316/17423
- [LaTeX Mode and Listings with $-signs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18975/2264)

Comment: OT: what theme/font are you using?

Comment: @Tyler The font looks like DejaVu Sans Mono. (A bit late but it's resurrection time… :-)

Comment: I can confirm it would've been DejaVu Sans Mono – as for the theme… that config is *long* gone, I'm afraid :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce what you're describing.  Your example looks like this for me (with latest AUCTeX from ELPA):

> [image]

You can try to eval the form `(font-latex-update-font-lock t)` and see if it helps.  Also, try to disable the theme you're using.  Otherwise, check your config again.